# How can i create a tool tip with rounded inverted triangle border?

Tags: html, css

i wonder how can i achieve a tool tip look like in the picture? with the rounded triangle with inverted borders, like in the bottom?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  margin: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #bada55;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.tooltip::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: -0.5em;
    bottom: -2em;
    left: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    border: 1em solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent #bada55 #bada55;
    
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">triangle</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Use image for that

Answer (score 1):

If your reference page is on the web as well, you could "inspect element" and peek how it's done, but chances are that it's an SVG or a plain image with both the tip and the shadow embedded (which is further suggested by how the right side of the shadow is drawn) - you aren't going to get an accurate replica of this through stitching rectangles alone.

Comment: And especially not if you want it to scale properly and work consistently cross-browser.